# Monetizing Windows phone apps via ads targeting india

Tags: windows-phone, ads, mobile-application

I am new to Windows phone (WP7 & WP8) development . I have developed 2 free Apps that are performing well in India. I have integrated Microsoft pub center ads in my apps, but there is no ad for india region.
Please let me know , how can I better monetize my apps ?

Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Try to contact Microsoft pub team India. They will serve you best.